# Javascript RegExp Object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use this function below to quickly find an item in a table
My problem is that this function only searches for text that contains the search string in the given table
I have been trying my best to modify it to match only the text that begins with the search string but not working.

```
function searchTable(inputVal)
{
    var table = $('#supplier_table_body');
    table.find('tr').each(function(index, row)
    {
        var allCells = $(row).find('td');
        if(allCells.length > 0)
        {
            var found = false;
            allCells.each(function(index, td)
            {
                var regExp = new RegExp(inputVal, '^i');
                if(regExp.test($(td).text()))
                {
                    found = true;
                    return false;
                }
            });
            if(found == true)$(row).show();else $(row).hide();
        }
    });
}
```

Here is my jquery

```
        $('#itemname').keyup(function()
    {
        searchTable($(this).val());
    });
```

Comment: As an aside, `if(found == true) ... else ...` can all be replaced by `$(row).toggle( found )`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [*string start* anchor](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) is not a [regex modifier flag](http://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html), but needs to be part of the expression:

```
var regExp = new RegExp('^'+inputVal, 'i');
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it works, but you may try to add a caret ( ^ ) before the inputVal, while creating the RegExp.

This should only allow words starting with inputVal.

Cheers,

EDIT:

Like so :

```
new RegExp("^" + inputVal, "i")
```

Comment: Thanx a lot Romain Sertelon This eventually worked for me. var regExp = new RegExp("^"+ inputVal, "i");

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use \b: `new RegExp("\\b" + inputVal, "i")`. It finds a match that begins with inputVal.

Comment: and also use `mg` flags next to your i in case the content of that cell is multilined.

Answer (score 0):

This answer posted as a community wiki answer because I think it solves the problem you're having and simplifies your code (but is too long to post as a comment), so I'd suggest, though currently untested, amending your function to:

```
function searchTable(needle){
    var table = $('#supplier_table_body'),
        cells = table.find('td');
    cells.filter(function(){
        return this.textContent.indexOf(needle) !== 0;
    }).closest('tr').hide();
}
```

[Simple proof of concept](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Y3Nx6/).